# Proof involving modulus and CRT

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let m,n be natural numbers where gcd(m,n) = 1. Suppose x is an integer which satisfies

x ≡ m (mod n)
x ≡ n (mod m)
Prove that x ≡ m+n (mod mn).

I know that since gcd(m,n)=1 means they are relatively prime so then given x, gcd(x,n)=m and gcd(x,m)=n. I have trouble getting to the next steps in proving x ≡ m+n (mod mn). Which is gcd(x, mn)=m+n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Chinese Remainder Theorem (uniqueness part) you know that, since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, the system of congruences has a **unique** solution modulo $mn$.

So we only need to check that $m+n$ **works**. For that, we only need to verify that $m+n\equiv n\pmod{m}$, and that $m+n\equiv m\pmod{n}$.  That is very easy!

Comment: Oh so prove gcd(m+n,m)=n?

Comment: You don't have to prove that, good thing too, since it is false. As the answer says, you have to show two almost identical things. You need to show that $m+n\equiv n\pmod{m}$ Is the difference $(m+n)-n$ divisible by $m$? Sure!

Comment: okay thanks so much, I think I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that $m n$ divides $x - (m + n)$. Since $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, the lcm of $m$ and $n$ is $mn$, so you have to prove that $m$ and $n$ divide $x - (m + n)$.

Let's do it for $n$. You have $x -(m+n) = (x -m) - n$, and by assumption you have that $n$ divides $x - m$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\rm\:x\:$ and $\rm\:x' = m+n\:$ are both solutions, it follows from CRT *uniqueness* that $\rm\:x \equiv x'\ (mod\ mn)\:$ since $\rm\:gcd(m,n)=1\:\Rightarrow\:\color{#C00}{lcm(m,n)} = mn.\:$ CRT uniqueness has a very simple proof, namely

$$\rm\:\begin{array}{l} x\equiv a\equiv x'\ \ (mod\ m)\\\rm x\equiv b\equiv x'\ \ (mod\ n)\end{array}\ \Rightarrow\ m,n\mid x- x'\ \Rightarrow\ lcm(m,n)\mid x-x'\ \Rightarrow\ x\equiv x'\ \ (mod\ \color{#C00}{lcm(m,n)})$$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, $ $ *uniqueness theorems* $ $ provide very powerful tools for deducing equalities. [See these prior posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniqueness+theorems+provide+powerful+tools) for many further examples.